# Identify which rows (or columns) have values in sparse Matrix

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

I need to identify the rows (/columns) that have defined values in a large sparse Boolean Matrix. I want to use this to 1. slice (actually `view`) the Matrix by those rows/columns; and 2. slice (/`view`) vectors and matrices that have the same dimensions as the margins of a Matrix. I.e. the result should probably be a Vector of indices / Bools or (preferably) an iterator.

I've tried the obvious:

```
a = sprand(10000, 10000, 0.01)
cols = unique(a.colptr)
rows = unique(a.rowvals)
```

but each of these take like 20ms on my machine, probably because they allocate about 1MB (at least they allocate `cols` and `rows`). This is inside a performance-critical function, so I'd like the code to be optimized. The Base code seems to have an `nzrange` iterator for sparse matrices, but it is not easy for me to see how to apply that to my case.

Is there a suggested way of doing this?

Second question: I'd need to also perform this operation on views of my sparse Matrix - would that be something like `x = view(a,:,:); cols = unique(x.parent.colptr[x.indices[:,2]])` or is there specialized functionality for this? Views of sparse matrices appear to be tricky (cf https://discourse.julialang.org/t/slow-arithmetic-on-views-of-sparse-matrices/3644 – not a cross-post)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `cols` implementation has a bug, for example `unique(speye(2).colptr)` is a 3 element vector. See full answer for more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding getting the non-zero rows and columns of a sparse matrix, the following functions should be pretty efficient:

```
nzcols(a::SparseMatrixCSC) = collect(i 
  for i in 1:a.n if a.colptr[i]<a.colptr[i+1])

function nzrows(a::SparseMatrixCSC)
    active = falses(a.m)
    for r in a.rowval
        active[r] = true
    end
    return find(active)
end
```

For a 10_000x10_000 matrix with 0.1 density it takes 0.2ms and 2.9ms for cols and rows, respectively. It should also be quicker than method in question (apart from the correctness issue as well).

Regarding views of sparse matrices, a quick solution would be to turn view into a sparse matrix (e.g. using `b = sparse(view(a,100:199,100:199))`) and use functions above. In code:

```
nzcols(b::SubArray{T,2,P}) where {T,P<:AbstractSparseArray} = nzcols(sparse(b))
nzrows(b::SubArray{T,2,P}) where {T,P<:AbstractSparseArray} = nzrows(sparse(b))
```

A better solution would be to customize the functions according to view. For example, when the view uses UnitRanges for both rows and columns:

```
# utility predicate returning true if element of sorted v in range r
inrange(v,r) = searchsortedlast(v,last(r))>=searchsortedfirst(v,first(r))

function nzcols(b::SubArray{T,2,P,Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}}
  ) where {T,P<:SparseMatrixCSC}
    return collect(i+1-start(b.indexes[2]) 
      for i in b.indexes[2]
      if b.parent.colptr[i]<b.parent.colptr[i+1] && 
        inrange(b.parent.rowval[nzrange(b.parent,i)],b.indexes[1]))
end

function nzrows(b::SubArray{T,2,P,Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}}
  ) where {T,P<:SparseMatrixCSC}
    active = falses(length(b.indexes[1]))
    for c in b.indexes[2]
        for r in nzrange(b.parent,c)
            if b.parent.rowval[r] in b.indexes[1]
                active[b.parent.rowval[r]+1-start(b.indexes[1])] = true
            end
        end
    end
    return find(active)
end
```

which work faster than the versions for the full matrices (for 100x100 submatrix of above 10,000x10,000 matrix cols and rows take 16μs and 12μs, respectively on my machine, but these are unstable results).

A proper benchmark would use fixed matrices (or at least fix the random seed). I'll edit this line with such a benchmark if I do it.

Comment: Thanks, those are a lot faster! 
I was a bit surprised to need to `collect` the generator in `nzcols` to use it for indexing that seems intuitively like it should be possible.
I've had `b.indexes[2]` (and 1)  have the value `Colon()` in which case the function fails, but I should be able to work out how to deal with that myself :-) (probably by defining wrapper functions for `start` and `inrange`.

Comment: No need for the `collect`, but for `nzrows` a generator is less obvious, so I wanted to keep the return type the same for rows and cols.

Comment: Also, a faster (but less readable) `nzcols`: `nzcols(a::SparseMatrixCSC) = (res=Vector{Int}(); foldl((x,y)->(if (x<a.colptr[y]) push!(res,y-1) end; a.colptr[y]),a.colptr[1],2:a.n+1) ; res)`

Comment: And `nzrows` in one-line: `nzrows(a::SparseMatrixCSC) = find(setindex!(falses(a.m),true,a.rowval))`

Comment: oohh, nice, I'll try that out!

Comment: The `second` nzcols implementation is like 40% faster, whereas the one-line `nzrows` is roughly 10% slower on my machine.

Comment: I am having issues getting the view functions working: e.g. `b = sprand(Bool, 10000, 10000, 0.01); d = view(bb, sample(1:10000, 100), 1:10000); find(sum(d,1) .> 0 # 6000; nzcols(d) #0; find(sum(d,2) .> 0 # all 100; nzrows(d) #BoundsError: attempt to access 100-element BitArray{1} at index [3596] #the error comes from the line active[b.parent...`

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard `nzcols` and `nzrows` for views were designed for range views. A different version is needed for arbitrary subsets of rows/columns. I'll see if I can fix this up.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) I have been trying to decipher the code to see if I could fix it myself - I'll certainly learn a lot about how sparse matrices work!

Comment: OK. Didn't add specific version for other view indices, but made sure the definitions direct dispatch to correct implementations. Keep checking stuff, there are always more bugs and opportunities for improvement.

Comment: Any hint about how I could go about extending this to non-range views? It is crucial to my implementation. And thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The trick would be a helper function which would calculate if the *intersection* of two *sorted* vectors is non-empty quickly. This would replace `inrange` function in current answer.

Comment: Here is one that is faster than Base.intersect: `function sortedintersect(v1, v2)
    ret = Vector{Base.promote_eltype(v1, v2)}(0);
    i,j = start(v1), start(v2);
    while i <= length(v1) && j <= length(v2) 
        if v1[i] == v2[j]
            push!(ret, v1[i]);
            i += 1;
        elseif v1[i] > v2[j]
            j += 1;
        else
            i += 1;
        end;
    end;
    ret;
end;`
Now to see if I can apply this.

Comment: I meant `function sortedintersecting(v1, v2)
    i,j = start(v1), start(v2);
    while i <= length(v1) && j <= length(v2) 
        if v1[i] == v2[j]
            return true;
        elseif v1[i] > v2[j]
            j += 1;
        else
            i += 1;
        end;
    end;
    false;
end;
`

Comment: Dan, what's the protocol here - I really appreciate your help, but I'm also really keen to get a reply on my last part of the question, with the non-range views. Is it best to reopen the answer with a note that only the last bit remains to be answered? Or document our efforts here in the comments? Or is it better to open a new question and link to this?

Comment: I'll add another answer with the non-range stuff. But it is not really optimal. Since non-range indices can also repeat and are not really sorted. So you might also disregard the `sortedintersect` bit. Adding another answer....

Answer (score 2):

In case the indices are not ranges, the fallback to converting to a sparse matrix works, but here are versions for indices which are Vectors. If the indices are mixed, yet another set of versions needs to be made. Quite repetitive, but this is the strength of Julia, when the versions are done, the code will choose optimized methods correctly using the types in the caller without too much effort.

```
function sortedintersecting(v1, v2)
    i,j = start(v1), start(v2)
    while i <= length(v1) && j <= length(v2)
        if v1[i] == v2[j] return true
        elseif v1[i] > v2[j] j += 1
        else i += 1
        end
    end
    return false
end

function nzcols(b::SubArray{T,2,P,Tuple{Vector{Int64},Vector{Int64}}}
  ) where {T,P<:SparseMatrixCSC}
    brows = sort(unique(b.indexes[1]))
    return [k 
      for (k,i) in enumerate(b.indexes[2])
      if b.parent.colptr[i]<b.parent.colptr[i+1] && 
        sortedintersecting(brows,b.parent.rowval[nzrange(b.parent,i)])]
end

function nzrows(b::SubArray{T,2,P,Tuple{Vector{Int64},Vector{Int64}}}
  ) where {T,P<:SparseMatrixCSC}
    active = falses(length(b.indexes[1]))
    for c in b.indexes[2]
      active[findin(b.indexes[1],b.parent.rowval[nzrange(b.parent,c)])] = true
    end
    return find(active)
end
```

-- ADDENDUM --

Since it was noted `nzrows` for Vector{Int} indices is a bit slow, this is an attempt to improve its speed by replacing `findin` with a version exploiting sortedness:

```
function findin2(inds,v,w)
    i,j = start(v),start(w)
    res = Vector{Int}()
    while i<=length(v) && j<=length(w)
        if v[i]==w[j]
            push!(res,inds[i])
            i += 1
        elseif (v[i]<w[j]) i += 1
        else j += 1
        end
    end
    return res
end

function nzrows(b::SubArray{T,2,P,Tuple{Vector{Int64},Vector{Int64}}}
  ) where {T,P<:SparseMatrixCSC}
    active = falses(length(b.indexes[1]))
    inds = sortperm(b.indexes[1])
    brows = (b.indexes[1])[inds] 
    for c in b.indexes[2]
      active[findin2(inds,brows,b.parent.rowval[nzrange(b.parent,c)])] = true
    end
    return find(active)
end
```

Comment: Turns out `sortedintersecting` was useful :). Copied the version from the comment and spaced it out a bit.

Comment: That `active[...]` line in `nzrows` is quite magical - was a bit surprised it worked out so succinctly.

Comment: Thanks so much! If only I could mark both as answers! :-)

Comment: Right! Done that straight away

Comment: Just for info, the `nzrows` for `Vector{Int}` is about a 1000 times slower than the other functions there. I've been playing with it most of the evening, but may find some serendipity tomorrow :-)

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Does the new function in the addendum perform better?

Comment: In fact it does - only 9 times slower than the UnitRange version, which is probably the fastest you can get. Interestingly, I tried the same thing yesterday (I made a function 100% identical to your findin2), but due to an omission error in the nzrows calling function I didn't notice it benchmarked horribly. Good to see I was on the right track!